# Should mobile webpages have hreflang links to non-mobile pages?

Tags: canonical-url, mobile, hreflang

My site has multilingual links, which are specified like this on non-mobile pages:

```
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://mydomain.com/page" />
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="jp" href="http://ja.mydomain.com/page" />
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko" href="http://ko.mydomain.com/page" />
```

In addition, these non-mobile pages link to a mobile version:

```
    <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="/mobile/page" />
```

Now the question is about what links should be in the mobile page, which isn't translated to different languages now.

Is this enough:

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="/page"/>
```

Or should I also have the same group of hreflangs that point to non-mobile pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on translating those pages, then you can hace the actual mobile version without localized links, of course you can also add some kind of message on your site/pages telling that to the visitor.

If you don't plan on translating the content, then you should provide those links. You still may serve the english (I assume is english) version and have some text telling your users that you are not going to provide a localized mobile version, but that you have a non mobile localized version so the can decide.

But remember, if you have a way to make the user's life easier, you should.